# Woocommerce custom price after actual price

Tags: woocommerce

I'm in search for a function that could help me to add a custom price for my woocommerce (7.2.2 version) shop products. (Only as text in frontend). I'm using the yith membership to give the discount to my customers already, but I have no option to display discounted prices before the users can buy the membership.

Example:

My price is 2$ and I want to add the following text after price: 1$ with subscription x.

demo:

```
  Product title
         2$
1$ with subscription x
```

The function need to calculate the price with subscription x using the following fixed discount

```
original price - 50% = subscription price
```

Also this need to have some condition if the product already have a discount.

```
    Product title
  <del>2$</del> 1.8$
0,9$ with subscription x
```

I tried some modules which allowed me to add some text as current price suffix, but there is no way to do a calculation of the custom price using those modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final solution : i added a 25% discount + custom text

```
function wptips_custom_html_addon_to_price(  $price, $product ) {

 $pretinitial = $price;
$sale_price = $product->sale_price;

if (!empty($sale_price)) {
    $pretfinalscos = $sale_price;
}
else 
{
    $pretfinalscos = $pretinitial;
}

   $pretfinal = preg_replace("/[^0-9,.]/", "", "$pretfinalscos");
        $pretfinal = str_replace(',', '.', $pretfinal);
         $pricegold = $pretfinal - ($pretfinal * (25 / 100));

 $html_price_suffix = '<span style="color:black;" class="price-suffix"> <br>Cu abonamentul Gold '.number_format((float)$pricegold, 2, '.', '').' lei</span>'; // custom suffix html that you want to add after price

 if ( !empty( $price ) ) {
     $price = $html_price_prefix . ' ' . $price . ' ' . $html_price_suffix;
      return $price;
    } else {
      return $price;
    }
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'wptips_custom_html_addon_to_price', 999, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price', 'wptips_custom_html_addon_to_price', 999, 2 );
```